# How to make Grouping Entities Table widget in Thingsboard?

Tags: widget, thingsboard

I created a widget with Entities Table widget where data is presented in table like this : [image]

I want to ask how to make grouping entity table widget or is it possible to create Entities Table widget similar like Hierarchy Widget in Widget Table Widget or As shown below :

[image]

Can the Entities Table widget display the data by grouping?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with default Entities Table Widget, but you could develop your own custom widget for this purpose.

There are a lot of libraries available like e.g. DataTables:

https://datatables.net/

https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Comment: Have you have the the example @mdeuchert thanks.